# How to automate IIS web applications using Jenkins with Team foundations server source code management tools

Tags: iis, jenkins, tfs

How to automate IIS web applications using Jenkins with Team foundations server source code management tools.
I am planning to automate IIS applications can you please provide me any documents which is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you want to queue Jenkins build automatically when there is a change in IIS web applications which hosted in TFS. You can check the steps below:

1. In Jenkins, add a new project, and in **Source Code Management**, select TFVC or Git (it depends on which version control type you use in TFS). Details you can refer to the link below:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/tfs-plugin/blob/master/README.md#job-configuration

2. In TFS/VSTS, add a new **Service Hook**, and select **Jenkins** and choose **Code checked in** or **Code pushed** event (it depends on which version control type you use in TFS).

[image]

With these two configurations, when there is a new check-in or push to the IIS web application, the Jenkins build will be triggered automatically. Here is a useful blog for your reference:

http://www.donovanbrown.com/post/Setting-up-CICD-with-the-TFS-Plugin-for-Jenkins

Comment: Cece Dong you're correct with VSTS and Git, but we are planning to Deploy IIS based applications using Jenkins through TFS. Step 1 - If I check-in something in TFS then same TFS code is automatically deployed by Jenkins using Poll SCM .

Comment: Do you mean you want to queue Jenkins build automatically when there is a change in IIS web applications which hosted in TFS?